# How to host custom Netty codec with Quarkus?

Tags: java, netty, vert.x, codec, quarkus

I am a total newbie to Quarkus, but I do know Netty and vert.x quite well. I have to do the deep dive and use Quarkus to open a server socket hosting a custom network codec written in Netty - instead of a REST service. I can't find documentation on this. Do you know any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good guide on how you can use natively vert.x and netty native transport with quarkus : https://quarkus.io/guides/vertx

You just need to import the quarkus dependancies and activate some configuration properties. Then you'll be able to inject vertx in your code and use it to handle asynchronous communication (using asynchronous http restful api through netty native transport or Linux native transport or the native eventbus or kafka or whatever).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this documentation. I hoped to get something more detailed, but I guess this is just because I don't know Quarkus too good, yet. So I will start working with Quarkus and get into it.